# How to create new pandas columns from a pandas data frame column content

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, separator

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ds1 = {'Name':["Juan Pablo Montoya","Jose Hiero","Martin Vasquez"], "Comments" : ["DOB 18 May 1967; POB Mexico.","POB Mexico.","-0-"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ds1)
```

Which looks like this:

```
print(df1)
                 Name                      Comments
0  Juan Pablo Montoya  DOB 18 May 1967; POB Mexico.
1          Jose Hiero                   POB Mexico.
2      Martin Vasquez                           -0-
```

I need to create two new columns based on the contents of the `Comments` column.
The names of the two new columns are:

- `DOB`
- `POB`

The values in column `DOB` is the value following DOB in the `Comments` column (up until the semi-colon).
The values in column `POB` is the value following POB in the `Comments` column (up until the dot).
If there is a value of "-0-" in the `Comments` then both new columns contain `NaN`.

So, from the example above, the resulting data frame would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `str.extract()`:

```
df1['DOB'] = df1['Comments'].str.extract('DOB (.*);+')
df1['POB'] = df1['Comments'].str.extract('POB (.*)')
```

Output:

```
    Name                Comments                        DOB           POB
0   Juan Pablo Montoya  DOB 18 May 1967; POB Mexico.    18 May 1967   Mexico.
1   Jose Hiero          POB Mexico.                     NaN           Mexico.
2   Martin Vasquez      -0-                             NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It cane be done with regex parsing:

```py
df1['DOB'] = df1['Comments'].str.extract(r'DOB (\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})')
df1['POB'] = df1['Comments'].str.extract(r'POB ([a-zA-Z\- .]+)')
```

Comment: @giampaolo Care to tell me why you un-accepted my answer after validating it? Genuinely interested to know why you prefer the other regex pattern to this one

Comment: I was trying to make it as flexible as possible, different date formats, etc. Your regexes are extremely specific to the small sample provided - I wonder if the larger dataset looked slightly different, and mine still caught it?